# Set input's ng-required validity from ng-form within ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

I want to set validity of my input field. I know I can do if with: `$scope.SOME_FORM_NAME.SOME_INPUT_NAME.$setValidity("required", true);`

The problem is that I need to access it first. My current page structure looks like this:

```
<div ...>   <!-- bootstrap -->
  <div ...>
    <div ng-switch="type">
      <div ng-switch-when="type_1">
        <div ...>
          <ng-form name="myForm" ng-submit="firstFunction()">
            <div ...>
              <input name="myInput" ng-model="some_model_1" ng-required="true" />
            </div>
          </ng-form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div ng-switch-when="type_2">
        <div ...>
          <ng-form name="myForm" ng-submit="secondFunction()">
            <div ...>
              <input .../>  <!-- Other inputs without validity -->
            </div>
          </ng-form>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Even shorter:

```
ng-switch
  ng-form name="myForm"
    input name="myInput"
```

This would make my validity setter: `$scope.myForm.myInput.$setValidity("required", true);`. Except that `ng-switch` prevents me to access `myForm` right away.

Here is what `console.log($scope)` spits out.

> $$ChildScope: ƒ ChildScope()
>
> $$childHead:ChildScope {$$childTail: Scope, $$childHead: Scope, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array(61), $$listeners: {…}, …}
>
> $$childTail:ChildScope {$$childTail: Scope, $$childHead: Scope, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: Array(61), $$listeners: {…}, …}
>
> $$listenerCount: {$destroy: 11, uib:datepicker.mode: 1}
>
> $$listeners: {}
>
> $$nextSibling: null
>
> $$prevSibling: Scope {$$childTail: ChildScope, $$childHead: ChildScope,
>
> $$nextSibling: Scope, $$watchers: Array(2), $$listeners: {…}, …}
>
> $$watchers: [{…}, $$digestWatchIndex: -1]
>
> $$watchersCount:65
>
> $id:6
>
> $parent: Scope {$$childTail: Scope, $$childHead: Scope, $$nextSibling: null, $$watchers: null, $$listeners: {…}, …}
>
> $resolve: {$transition$: Transition, $stateParams: {…}, $state$: {…}}
>
> type: "type_1"

I can only see `myForm` from `$$childHead` and `$$childTail`, so I need to change something that let's me access the form differently.

(Do I change the structure so it works somehow with ng-switch, if so then how? Or do I use something else that bypasses ng-switch to ng-form?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the `required` attribute of an input, use an Angular Expression with the [`ng-required` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired).

```
  <ng-form name="myForm" ng-submit="firstFunction()">
      <input name="myInput" ng-model="some_model_1"
       ng-required="myInputRequired" />
  </ng-form>
```

Then in the controller:

```
 $scope.myInputRequired = true;
```

My using a Model variable, the `required` attribute will be set when the `ng-switch` directive instantiates the `<input>` element.

[The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/6zDUWBWYoxK8uaWUslH6?p=preview)

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app>
    <form name="form1" ng-init="type='type_1'">
    <div ng-switch="type">
      <div ng-switch-when="type_1">
          <ng-form name="myForm" ng-submit="firstFunction()">
              <input name="myInput" ng-model="some_model_1"
               ng-required="myInputRequired" />
          </ng-form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>  
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myInputRequired"/>
    myInputRequired={{myInputRequired}}
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="type" ng-true-value="'type_1'">
    type={{type}}
    <br>
    <p ng-show="form1.myForm.$error.required">
      ERROR: Input required
    </p>

  </body>
```